# Not-So-Lazy Fetching of Transitive Associations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, fetch, many-to-one

I've been experiencing a problem with excessive select statements bogging down our database, and I'm curious if anybody can shed some light on the situation. The code I've provided below shows the basic structure of the relationships that seem to be giving us the problem.

We use a `@MappedSuperclass` to provide `@Id` and `@Version` for all of our classes. Class A and class B have a many-to-many relationship managed through `OccurrenceOfB`, but there is also extra information (not shown) associated with each `OccurrenceOfB` instance (hence why we are not merely using a `JoinTable`).

The problem becomes manifest when we attempt to create a string representation of A. In this case, I'm actually constructing JSON, but I've excluded the bulk of that here. The pertinent code, included below, involves iterating over all `OccurrenceOfB`s in the A and getting the ID of each. However, when we do this (and specifically, when the iteration begins), Hibernate is retrieving all of the `OccurrenceOfB` objects. This is just as I would expect. However, at the same time, it is also retrieving all of the corresponding B objects, and the C objects associated with each B. In other words, when it lazily retrieves the `OccurrenceOfBs`, it is then eagerly fetching the rest of the entity graph and not honouring the `FetchType.LAZY` annotations (which are admittedly, according to the documentation, merely a hint). This is not what I would expect--and is causing some significant performance hits when the size of A.occurrences is in the thousands. (Our actual objects are slightly more complex than this, but serializing one A with 1500 `OccurrenceOfB`s results in 10502 select statements in our system.)

Curiously, the opposite does not hold true. If I have a B that occurs in 1500 As, converting the B to a string (which likewise iterates over the occurrences collection and retrieves the ID of each) does NOT perform all of the excessive select statements.

And now, at long last to the actual question: How can I improve performance in my database in this scenario? Setting the default batch fetch size provides some relief, but it seems to be a band-aid on the underlying problem. Ideally, how can I convince Hibernate to actually honour lazy fetching for transitive associations?

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class PersistentObject
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    protected Long id;

    @Version
    @Column
    protected Long version;
}


@Entity
public class A extends PersistentObject
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a",
               fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               orphanRemoval = true,
               cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private final Set<OccurrenceOfB> occurrences = new HashSet<>();

    // Other columns here

   @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        // ...
        List<Long> ids = new LinkedList<>();
        for ( OccurrenceOfB occurrence : occurrences )
        {
            ids.add(occurrence.getId());
        }
        // ...
    }
}

@Entity
public class OccurrenceOfB extends PersistentObject
{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
                           CascadeType.MERGE },
               optional = false)
    private A a;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
                           CascadeType.MERGE },
               optional = false)
    private B b;

    // Other columns here
}

@Entity
public class B extends PersistentObject
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b",
               fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               orphanRemoval = true,
               cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private final Set<OccurrenceOfB> occurrences = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
              cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },
              optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "c",
                nullable = false)
    private C c;

    // Other columns here
}

@Entity
public class C extends PersistentObject
{
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "c",
              optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b",
                nullable = false)
    private B b;

    // Other columns here
}
```

Follow-Up:
So, with some more investigation I think I've identified the problem--and it wasn't in any of the code I had mirrored here.  It was actually a faulty implementation of equals/hashCode.  Because OccurrenceOfB is pretty much defined by the A and B to which it references, both values were being referenced in equals/hashCode.  As a result, the mere act of iterating over the collection was triggering a fetch.  Because B had a similar implementation (that referenced C), it was performing yet another transitive fetch.

I've removed the implementations entirely and saw that my 10502 select statements was reduced to 3--and that's an improvement I can get behind.  Obviously a proper implementation of equals/hashCode will be required (and will be fun given the caveats indicated in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html), but that is beyond the scope of this post.

Thank you very much for your help and thought on this!

Comment: Can you post the code that loads an instance of A?

Comment: The code loading it is pretty straightforward (I think): `A a = manager.find(A.class, id);   String s = a.toString();`

Comment: @DavidLevesque I never heard anything like that before. I know that a class final will not be lazy loaded, but a final in a collection I did not saw any problem before. Do you have a link that detail this? Thanks!